# Cookie cutter template docker crash when I run my API which get data from Google API or any other third party API?

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a django API where I used cookiecutter template for rapid development also I used docker to run their APIs; now  the problem is:

1. I  have a one API in which I calling a one thirdparty Google API for get some data then save it to my database and return API response as a result what some time crash I see the error is my docker is reload automatic while API is progress? Now what should I do for it give me proper solution?

```
 |  * Restarting with watchdog (inotify)
 | 2023-09-26 06:58:26.032 UTC [50] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction   

 | Performing system checks...
```

I try to call a third party API and get that data and to database.

Comment: Hey, looks like your Docker might be restarting because of some issues in the app, or maybe it needs more resources? Check the Docker logs with docker logs containerName/Id to get some hints. Also, look over your code where you’re calling that API and savng to the database. Make sure you handle any errors properly so it doesn’t crash. Oh, and setting DEBUG = False in Dango and using a production server like Gunicorn could help too!